# What is the difference between clustered index and no indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

So i know what is clustered index and non clustered index..

But is it same as to create a index for one column in a table and leave other columns in the same table  without creating any indexes rather than creating a non clustered index on other columns?

I am bit confused , please clarify?

Comment: Have you researched this ? Look at:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms190457.aspx

Comment: I've read your question three times and still not quite sure what is it that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to think about it is like DVDs on a shelf. You've already decided to cluster the dvds by type (of dvd). After that you might want to sort(index) them another way (alphabetically by name or by year released). Doing this helps you find DVDs easier and it's roughly the same in SQL.

When used correctly indexes can speed up your queries as less work is required to find what is expected from the query.